# Kryo causing buffer underflow exception on read

Tags: java, deserialization, kryo

I am serializing with:

```
    private byte[] serialize()
{
    KryoPool pool = new KryoPool.Builder(factory).softReferences().build();
    Kryo kryo = pool.borrow();
    Output output = new Output(0, 1024);
    kryo.writeClassAndObject(output, readsSetNode);
    byte[] bytes = output.toBytes();
    output.close();
    pool.release(kryo);
    return bytes;
}
```

and deserializing:

```
KryoPool pool = new KryoPool.Builder(factory).softReferences().build();
        Kryo kryo = pool.borrow();

        Input input = new Input(bytes);
        HashMap<NodeStorage, NodeStorage> deserialized = (HashMap<NodeStorage, NodeStorage>) kryo.readClassAndObject(input);
        input.close();

        pool.release(kryo);
```

The hashmap "deserialized" contains the object correctly but unfortunately the log is spammed with a buffer underflow exception:
It seems this only happens when I try to debug the application.
Does this cause any problems or is that behaviour normal?

> com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Buffer underflow.
>       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.require(Input.java:199)
>       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.readVarInt(Input.java:373)
>       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:127)
>       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:693)
>       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:804)
>       at main.java.com.bag.server.TestServer.appExecuteUnordered(TestServer.java:78)
>       at bftsmart.tom.server.defaultservices.DefaultRecoverable.executeUnordered(DefaultRecoverable.java:417)
>       at bftsmart.tom.ServiceReplica.receiveReadonlyMessage(ServiceReplica.java:214)
>       at bftsmart.tom.core.DeliveryThread.deliverUnordered(DeliveryThread.java:289)
>       at bftsmart.tom.core.TOMLayer.requestReceived(TOMLayer.java:290)
>       at bftsmart.communication.client.netty.NettyClientServerCommunicationSystemServerSide.channelRead0(NettyClientServerCommunicationSystemServerSide.java:184)
>       at bftsmart.communication.client.netty.NettyClientServerCommunicationSystemServerSide.channelRead0(NettyClientServerCommunicationSystemServerSide.java:61)
>       at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:292)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:278)
>       at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:277)
>       at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:264)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:292)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:278)
>       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:962)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:485)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:399)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:371)
>       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
>       at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Not sure if this is it, but I'd try constructing your Output with a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

I had meet the same issue, you should modify your serialize function like this:

```
    private byte[] serialize()
{
    KryoPool pool = new KryoPool.Builder(factory).softReferences().build();
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Kryo kryo = pool.borrow();
    Output output = new Output(byteArrayOutputStream);
    kryo.writeClassAndObject(output, readsSetNode);
    output.close();
    pool.release(kryo);
    byte[] bytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();;
    return bytes;
}
```